# Adopting OWASP security recommendation using Keycloak, Java backend and Javascript frontend

Tags: jwt, keycloak, owasp

I was checking OWASP cheatsheet on how to improve security in a frontend client using a JWT to interact with the backend.

The approach they suggest is to basically add a claim in the JWT which contains an encoded "fingerprint" which is also sent via a hardened cookie.

The fingerprint is verified in the backend by checking that the claim and the cookie contains the same fingerprint. [Here the OWASP Cheatsheet entry](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java.html#token-storage-on-client-side)

When using Keycloak, is it possible to use such approach? Is Keycloak JavaScript adapter "secure" enough?